# Model diagnostics for multivariate linear regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

I am wondering whether there is a routine way to diagnose a multivariate linear model. For example:

```
y   <- rmvt(n=100, sigma=diag(3), df=3)  # 3 response vars as spherical multivariate t-dist
x1  <- rchisq(100, 2)                    # x1 distributed as chi-squared
x2  <- rt(100)                           # x2 distributed as t
fit <- lm(as.matrix(y)~x1+x2)            # fits the multivariate regression
```

How can you diagnose whether the model is fitted well?

Comment: Are you asking in general, or are you asking specifically how to do this in R? Note that the latter would br off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)).

Comment: In general.And may be better then in R.

Comment: I think this Q is on-topic, then. Is there any specific model diagnostic you are interested in? Are you just interested in a lack of fit test, or what all of the diagnostics that should be standard are?

Comment: Diagnostic for Univariate model is well set up, but I did not see a routine diagnostics method for multivariate models where the response has more than two variables like here.

Comment: What is your goal in estimating the model? There are plenty of direct and indirect diagnostics but they aren't all appropriate in every situation.